# Monitor Microsoft MSSQL Process - sqlservr - Division throug logical Processor possible?

Tags: zabbix

we use a zabbix 2.2 Appliance and are trying to get the following Performance Counter Data.
perf_counter[\Process(sqlservr)\% Processor Time]

We have the same Problem as described in this Forum Post:
https://www.zabbix.com/forum/showthread.php?t=16759

Does anyone know, if it is possible to divide the Data through the 16 (Logical Processor Count).

Sorry for my English!
:)

Answer (score 0):

If i check perf counter for mssql there is no perf counter for vcpu/core .

To check perf counter available on your mssql server do that:

select *
from sys.dm_os_performance_counters

But if you do the perfcounter from windows view there is counter for every vcpu/core.